# How to profile hibernate JPA session information?

Tags: java, performance, spring, hibernate, jpa

We have Spring Hibernate JPA web application in production. There is suspect of memory leak in session objects. We are uploading excel records using Apache POI into MYSQL.  Commit frequency is 10 records, but each commit takes 5 to 10 seconds pause and CPU reaches almost 100% throughout the import process.  Is there any way to profile the hibernate sessions in my application and find what process is causing such a high CPU usage. I was checking out Rhinos Hibernate Profiler but it seems to confusing in configuration and needs changes in code. Since we need to profile production or stage instance, is there any JPA Hibernate Session information profiler without much changes to application configuration/code?

Answer (score 2):

Use Visual VM, with all the plug-ins installed.  Attach it to your app's JVM PID when you start it up.  It'll show you memory, threads, and lots more.

I don't think it'll be a good idea to profile on a production server.  Put that code on another box and run a significant load for a long period of time.  That'll show the problem.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. It does not provide information about whats happening on particular hibernate session. I'm not really sure if we can see how many object reside in the session using this tool.

Comment: Click on profiling.  You'll see all the objects created, but only if you have all the plugins installed.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the JConsole plugin you're looking for?

http://hibernate-jcons.sourceforge.net/